# My code uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have a code that can run for one version, but for the latest cant. Android studio writes:
"uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details."

My code is:

```
 Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Words reminder");
        builder.setContentText("It's time to try yourself!");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        //builder.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        builder.setSound(alarmSound);

        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, RightOrNot.class);
        notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, 0);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notificationCompat = builder.build();
        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        managerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationCompat);
```

I believe the problem is in the first line:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
```

Do you know how can I fix the line or use something different that will work for the all versions?

Comment: It is only a warning. You Van ignore it.

Comment: But it doesnt work at the other phones that uses the latest version

Comment: You have to create a notification channel for oreo and the above versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the android developer docs `public Builder(Context context)` is deprecated and you should try using `public Builder(Context context, String channelID)` instead. You need to use a notification channel. Follow the steps [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java).

Comment: Thank you, but it doesnt help, the same warning and still cannot send a notification to the latest versions of phones(

Comment: Why have you accepted an answer that you say doesn't help?

Comment: The issue must lie within your builder function call since the api docs says that builder function is deprecated. What issues are you getting now? Where is the problem?